# The set of zero divisors of a quotient ring over an irreducible ideal

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose that $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ an irreducible ideal of $R$.

Let $J$ be the set of zero divisors of $\frac{R}{I}$, i.e., $J=\{ r\in R \; |\; rs\in I\; \text{for some s}\; \in R\setminus I\}$.

It is easy to show that $J$ is an ideal of $R$.   But my question is that is $J$ a prime ideal of $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $ 1 \notin J $.  Next, suppose that $ x y \in J $, so $ x y s \in I $ for some $ s \notin I $.  If $ y s \in I $, then $ y \in J $; else if $ y s \notin I $, then since $ x y s \in I $, $ x \in J $.  Either way, $ x \in J $ or $ y \in J $, so $ J $ is prime.

It seems to me that the primality of $ J $ has nothing in particular to do with the irreducibility of $ I $ as such (or indeed even whether $ I $ is an ideal); $ I $ only needs to be irreducible to make $ J $ into an ideal in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. As you told I could proved $J$ is an ideal by the condition " J is irreducible". Thank you.